# How do I initialize variables and let them be used with the scanner?

Tags: java

I am trying to find the area using this formula, however, variables a, b, and c are not initialized.  How do I initialize them and let them be used with the scanner?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PA2 
{   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.##");

       float a, b, c;
       float s = (a + b + c);
       float pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6;
       double Area;

       pt1 = (s - a);
       pt2 = (s - b);
       pt3 = (s - c);
       pt4 = (s * pt1);
       pt5 = (pt4 * pt2);
       pt6 = (pt5 * pt3);
       Area = Math.sqrt(pt6);

       System.out.println("Enter first side: ");
       a = scan.nextFloat();
       System.out.println("Enter second side: ");
       b = scan.nextFloat();
       System.out.println("Enter third side: ");
       c = scan.nextFloat();
       System.out.println("Your area is: " + fmt.format(Area));

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to define in the paper the order and the algorithm before you start to write the code...

your approach is not so bad, just order the sequence in the code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.##");

//1. delcare the variables and initialize it...
float a = 0f;
float b = 0f;
float c = 0f;

//2. get the input 
System.out.println("Enter first side: ");
a = scan.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Enter second side: ");
b = scan.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Enter third side: ");
c = scan.nextFloat();

//3. Do the Math behind the scenes

float s = (a + b + c);
float pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6;
double Area;
pt1 = (s - a);
pt2 = (s - b);
pt3 = (s - c);
pt4 = (s * pt1);
pt5 = (pt4 * pt2);
pt6 = (pt5 * pt3);
Area = Math.sqrt(pt6);

//4. Print the results....
System.out.println("Your area is: " + fmt.format(Area));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it so that instead of just

```
float a, b, c;
```

it's:

```
float a=0;
float b=0;
float c=0;
```

Which initializes the variables. I had the same issue with another program. Hope this helps.